# Is there a program to emulate a MediaWiki editor?

Tags: windows, mediawiki

What I'm looking for would basically look like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Sandbox?action=edit), with previewing and *preferably* export to PDF.

This would basically be something like a TeX engine, but using MediaWiki markup.

It would also need to run on Windows.

Comment: Which editor that link opens depends heavily on your Wikipedia user settings.

Comment: Actually, I've realized that a command-line compiler (like a TeX engine) would work quite well; Notepad would work fine for writing.

Comment: You could use the [parse API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext) from the command line. The exact HTML output depends heavily on the wiki configuration and the contents of other pages, so an offline parser is not possible.